# How to put a dropdown inside another in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm designing a sidebar for mobile and trying to create a dropdown within another dropdown using bootstrap 3 but I do not get it and I do not understand what happens.

When I try to access the dropdown within another one, the two dropdown closes and I do not understand what I should do.

I think it's css problem but I do not know what happens.

```js
//function sidebar
window.onload = function() {
  window.jQuery ? $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sidebarNavigation .navbar-collapse").hide().clone().appendTo("body").removeAttr("class").addClass("sideMenu").show(), $("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>"), $(".navbar-toggle").on("click", function() {
      $(".sideMenu").addClass($(".sidebarNavigation").attr("data-sidebarClass")), $(".sideMenu, .overlay").toggleClass("open"), $(".overlay").on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("open"), $(".sideMenu").removeClass("open")
      })
    }), $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".navbar-toggle").is(":hidden") ? $(".sideMenu, .overlay").hide() : $(".sideMenu, .overlay").show()
    })
  }) : console.log("sidebarNavigation Requires jQuery")
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  // dropdown animation
  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(250);
  });
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(0);
  });
});
```

```css
.overlay,
.sideMenu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0
}

.overlay {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  right: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: 998;
  transition: all ease 20ms
}

.sideMenu,
.sidebarNavigation {
  z-index: 999;
  margin-bottom: 0
}

.overlay.open {
  left: 0;
  right: 0
}

.sidebarNavigation .left-navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 15px
}

.sideMenu {
  left: -100%;
  top: 52px;
  transition: all ease-in-out .4s;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 50%
}

.sideMenu.open {
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto
}

.sideMenu ul {
  margin: 0
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #69306d;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #91209a;
  border-color: #8f4195;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #91209a;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #91209a;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-control i {
  position: relative !important;
}

.open>.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.dropdown-menu {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-toggle:after {
  display: none;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding-left: 15px !important;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
  padding-bottom: 10px !important;
  padding-left: 25px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse sidebarNavigation" data-sidebarClass="navbar-inverse" style="background-color: #904296;border-color:#904296;border-color: #8f4195;position:fixed;top:0px;width: 100%;">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle left-navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="color:white;" href="#">My sidebar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar" style="background-color: #8f4195;border-color:#8f4195;">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav animated">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" id="drop2" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle test" role="button">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" id="drop2" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle test" role="button">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Taaaaa</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Caaaaers</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">aaaaaars</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Team Bios</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Customers</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" role="menuitem">Careers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

/* Fixed sidenav, full height */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

/* Style the sidenav links and the dropdown button */
.sidenav a, .dropdown-btn {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

/* On mouse-over */
.sidenav a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Main content */
.main {
  margin-left: 200px; /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 20px; /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

/* Add an active class to the active dropdown button */
.active {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

/* Dropdown container (hidden by default). Optional: add a lighter background color and some left padding to change the design of the dropdown content */
.dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: #262626;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Style the caret down icon */
.fa-caret-down {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Some media queries for responsiveness */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Dropdown 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-container">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Search</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar Dropdown</h2>
  <p>Click on the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu inside the side navigation.</p>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
  <p>Some random text..</p>
</div>

<script>
/* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content - This allows the user to have multiple dropdowns without any conflict */
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
  } else {
  dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
  }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```